# How to "suggest" an edit when you have full edit privileges?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

Every now and then I see a post which I believe could be improved a little. This could be rewriting their code to remove unnecessary parts so that their question/answer is more readable.

However, sometimes I feel like it would be better for the post's author to approve my edit, to make sure they're happy with it before it changes for everyone to see.

**Is there any way to suggest an edit (for the OP to approve) when having the edit privilege unlocked?**

I know users can rollback the edit, but if they happen to go offline they won't be able to make this change until they're back online again.

Comment: The post owner can always rollback your edit. If they happen to be online when you make your edit, they'll receive a notification to review your edit and approve or reject it directly. So I'd say things already behave as you'd want.

Comment: And suggested edits go to the suggested edit review queue, so they it wouldn't be necessaritly the author the one who approves rejects the suggestion.

Comment: So if I have the edit privilege and the OP of the question/answer is online and I edit their question they will be notified to accept/reject my edit? I thought that any edit I provide when I have the edit privilege will be automatically applied.

Comment: It will be automatically applied. But the post author will get a notification, and can review the edit. At least I think it's that way. If you do not mind, we'll experiment with me making a tiny edit on your question here.

Comment: You're trusted with your privileges. If you want an extra pair of eyes / strong opinions about an edit you plan to make join a chatroom and ask there. [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is open for those kind of discussions but other rooms that match the topic of the question being edited might work as well. Do check room rules before asking.

Comment: @yivi I didn't get the option to approve or reject. I just got a notifcation letting me know my post was editted

Comment: Which you can use to rollback the edit if you want. Close enough, IMO.

Comment: @yivi yes, I suppose it is an option, won't argue with that. I'm just thinking if they happen to go offline then they're post will be edited for all to see. I suppose rollback is a good enough tool though

Comment: @yivi "If they happen to be online when you make your edit, they'll receive a notification", no, if the edit triggers the notification (there are some cases where it doesn't) they will be notified whenever they are online or not when the edit is made. The only notifications you don't get when you are online are chat-based ones.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer you want since as Cerbrus said "you can't", but everyone can always suggest an edit *as anonymous user* while being logged out (e.g. incognito/privacy mode).

Comment: If you suggest the edit as anonymouse user, the edit goes in the review queue. Chances are quite high that edits which remove code (or alter code at all) get rejected there.

Comment: @BDL yes, I do suppose that is a downside of it being put into a review queue rather than it being solely an edit for the OP to see.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't.

As a trusted user, your edits will always be directly applied. There is no way to push a edit into the review queue, manually.

---

If you really want to make sure the author agrees with your intended edit, you could ask him in a comment, before making the edit.

Comment: I'm not too sure about asking in the comments as that might create noise (back and forth). You can always just make the edit and the OP can roll it back if it not correct.

Comment: @Script47: Edits and rollbacks without any form of communication are also somewhat noisy. It a bit of a _"best of two evils"_ choice, in my opinion.

Comment: you can also double the noise: edit and comment on the edit :)

Comment: @Script47 The comments may be noise after the edit is made, but discussing improvements to the post is *exactly what comments are for*. Once a decision has been reached wrt. the edit, you and the OP can always delete your comments, as those comments will no longer be needed. If you don't clean up after yourself, then someone else can flag them as "no longer needed".

Answer (score 14):

Log out (or open an incognito window with your browser), and you can make anonymous suggested edits.

[image]
[image]

It may be restricted to posts at least one day old, but you should see similar buttons:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create a second account on Stack Overflow, keep it under 2k reputation, and use it for suggesting edits. Having multiple accounts is not against the rules, which [have been stated as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

**if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse**

Oh wait.

No, you can't do that.

Comment: You can make anonymous suggested edits: no need for a second account. ;)

Comment: @Cœur that looks like a valid answer