# Ask the owner of a post whether they agree with an edit

Tags: discussion, edits

I have the [edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Now, there was a post that wasn't clear enough, and I thought I could improve it.

However, I wasn't sure that I understood the original poster (OP) correctly. Previously, before having this privilege, I would suggest an edit and wait. If the author was accepting the edit, or other people, I would know it is correct. But now, my edit will apply immediately, and I won't know whether it was correct.

I would like to communicate with the author of the post in order to ask them about their intention. Or at least ask other people whether they think this was the intention. Can I do this?

Related: [How to communicate with an editor in case of you not agreeing with an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348873/how-to-communicate-with-an-editor-in-case-of-you-not-agreeing-with-an-edit)

Comment: Ask OP to clarify their question then, don't edit.

Comment: *I would know it is correct.* - if the author accepted the edit, it might be correct, but the approval from the edit queue is more or less worthless in this regard.

Comment: @jps [*"if the author accepted the edit, it might be correct"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393396/7910454)

Comment: @leonheess might or might not, you never know

Comment: Also related: [How to "suggest" an edit when you have full edit privileges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379344)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to suggest an edit as an anonymous user in a private tab?

Comment: You really shouldn't do that, @jrh. There's an implicit assumption in this question that either (A) the original poster will review the suggested edit, or (B) the reviewers will make correct judgments with respect to the author's intent. Neither is true in the common case. If you can't convince yourself that the edit is correct and would be appreciated, then it's really best not to make the edit, whether you have full editing privileges or not.

Comment: "I would like to communicate with the author of the post in order to ask them about their intention." - well... that's what comments are for.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you have [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), there's no way for you to submit an edit for review. As with all privileges earned on this site, using them is not optional: if you've earned them, they'll always be used.

When you're uncertain whether an edit is appropriate, you have two options:

1. Don't make the edit at all. Instead, leave a comment underneath the post describing the edit(s) you have in mind and suggesting that the original poster make the edits. Leave it entirely up to their discretion whether they agree with your suggestions and are willing to make the edit.

   Note: This is the same strategy you use when you're too lazy to make the edit yourself. :-) The drawback here is it requires that the original poster still be around on the site and be reading comments on their posts. If they aren't, then it's unlikely they'll ever see, much less heed, your advice.
2. Go ahead and make the edit, doing your honest best to preserve the author's intent while still improving the post in the way you see fit. If the original poster truly disagrees with your edit, then they can easily roll it back. Chances are, your edit will be fine, and you've saved everyone a lot of extra work.

Comment: If the OP is no longer around, someone else might incorporate the edit in the future.  Especially if they see it's been e.g. 2 years since the suggested edit and the poster hasn't responded to the comment.

Comment: How would they know it is correct, @M.Justin? :-)

Comment: Fair enough, though by that point it's probably less important what the original asker intended than whether it's a useful question in its own right and consistent with the already given answers. 

Comment: "As with all privileges earned on this site, using them is not optional" - You mean except this one https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

Comment: An inexperienced OP may not yet be aware that they can edit their post. A friendly comment that they can [edit] their post may be pertinent.

Answer (score 22):

If you look at it and think:

> ... not sure that I understood the original poster (OP) correctly.

then you shouldn't make any edit.

Move on and leave it to other users.

In my opinion this also applies when a user hasn't got edit-privilege yet.

Only edit a question (or answer) when you are confident that your edit is an improvement and preserve the author's intent.

Comment: I do agree. However, I'd make an exception for formatting/grammar related edits where you can objectively improve a post even if you're not sure of OP's intentions. I often make an edit to format a piece of code, or even make it into a runnable snippet, while also commenting to ask for clarification.

Comment: @VLAZ Agree. Coding formating is fine (in most cases). However, even code format edits shall be done with "some care". For instance, don't change format-style just because you prefer another style than the one used. In e.g. C there isn't a single "accepted style" so we must accept the authors choice instead of starting a "style-battle". But for sure - fixing commonly accepted things like e.g. missing indentation is fine.

Comment: Oh, definitely. I go for unformatted code as it's something that REALLY hampers understanding a question. And if a user does add more info, they are unlikely to format the code. After all, they didn't do it the first time they posted, chances are low they'd do it in an edit.

Answer (score 16):

TL;DR: I sometimes edit already at 95% certainty.

I do not edit anything if I am not sure about it.
But in contrast to the 100% certainty mentioned in other answers here (which I basically agree with), I do, in situations which I will explain below, already edit at around 95%.

This is when I

- have asked clarification questions in comments
- have gotten feedback from the OP
- interpret the feedback as confirmation of what I wrote (we are talking "language barriers" here; on both sides, because I am not a native English speaker myself)
- see indications that OP tries to act on my proposals/questions (edit attempts, explanations in comments, etc.)
- am convinced that I can apply my proposals in a way which makes the post better than what the OP is likely to achieve soon (a bit of vanity here, I admit)
- worry that the current state is misleading, confusing, distracting, etc.

Then I edit, possibly making some assumptions of what the OP means (here is the missing 5%). I do my best at it.
Then I comment something like. "I took the liberty of editing in order to ... Please double check that it is what we have discussed. If not, please accept my apology and either undo or [edit] to fix my edit. I won't interfere again."

I do this for improving the post faster, for showing the details of markdown - and a little bit to provoke clarification of whatever I perceive as still being unclear.

I have until now always received an appreciative comment back. Usually they praise my edit and thank me for it (sorry for singing my own praises here). In rare cases they built on my edit and added more information or fixed a detail, which is exactly my goal.

Comment: I agree with and endorse this. If you are confident that an edit is correct, believe it respects the author's intent, and feel that it makes the post better overall for future viewers, then you should definitely make the edit. I'm a huge fan of editing, and I don't think people should trip all over themselves waiting for 100% certainty. I did not mean my answer to suggest otherwise. Thanks for pointing this out explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Make the edit and follow the post. If the OP rolls your edit back, then you'll get notified and you can ping them asking exactly why they rolled back your edit.

If the OP is rolling back your edit out of vengeance (meaning they don't want their post to be edited) then simply move on. It is their loss if they don't want a high quality post.

If you don't understand what the OP is trying to say, then maybe before making the edit you could also ask them in the comments what they are trying to say.

Comment: The OP may also be rolling back because they disagree with your improvement.  (I did this just today. 'Cos I thought the supposed improvement was actually invalidating a point I was trying to make in my answer.)  Either way, "just move on" is the correct response if your attempt to be helpful is rolled back.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not sure that moving on immediately is always necessary. I've had several situations where the OP rolled back because they simply misunderstood how community editing works (this is not restricted to low rep users either). It may not be a good idea to roll back the OP's roll back, but leaving a comment explaining why you made the edit, and asking why they rolled back the improvement is a reasonable approach I think.

Answer (score 3):

One still can leave an explicit edit reason, when there is information to add for the owner... and in case they shouldn't agree, they can deny or roll back the edit with a click. This argument about the content could be considered similar to some Chutzpah - therefore the edit reason should be a good argument. And even if the edit might by partially wrongful, one still can meet somewhere in the middle (eg. when I don't agree with an edit, I'd simply roll it back and may edit it myself).

Answer (score -4):

Extending the other answers, it depends also on the OP. The OPs typically

- don't know that their post is editable by others,
- don't come back or don't react comments.

The post that they've written is common knowledge ([CC-BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses) or so). The site has its rules, where and how can it be changed. One of the rules is that editing against the intent of the OP is forbidden. But this is the rule of the site, and the site could have an opposite rule without any problem.

But if the intent of the OP is unclear, you are free to fix it.

If you want to fix a whole post, but you only partially can do that, then do it partially. Improving something is never a problem and it never should be.

The same is if your edit targets to save the post from the closure. Obviously having a post, which might be edited against the OP's intent, is not what we want. But if it has only a little chance, while your edit saves it from the closure by a high chance, then yes doing it is better.

In such cases, I typically also drop a comment, roughly so:

> "I made the ... part more clear, I think probably this is what you think. The goal is to save your post from being closed as unclear. If you disagree, feel free to rollback."

I can't remember a single case as it had been rolled back, a "thanks" comment is far more likely.

Comment: "One of the rules is that editing against the intent of the OP is forbidden" [citation needed] the relevant help page doesn't mention "intent" https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @Braiam For what it's worth, there is a [canonical edit rejection reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits): _**clearly conflicts with author's intent**_, with the description _"This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."_ Detailed guidelines of adequate conduct exist in more places than just the help center.

Comment: This of course, does not give an author the right to reject any edit that comes in their way regardless of the changes made, but that is not what is being discussed here.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator the thing with that message is that the [same person that wrote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238333/213575) (aka Shog) also said ["The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple: 1) clarify meaning without changing it; 2) always respect the original author. Crucially, there's nothing about intent there"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066). When Shog said intent, it actually meant "meaning" as is "you should kept the post semantically equivalent". Your intent is usually "ask a question" or "answer a question".

Comment: On that we agree. I suppose _goals_ could be another keyword here. Content which deviates from the main goal, namely meta-commentary, should be removed when editing.

Comment: This answer reads like it was written by GPT heh

Comment: @forresthopkinsa What is a "GPT heh"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3